# Food Identification: Restaurant outside Batu Caves in Malaysia, what did we eat?

Tags: indian-cuisine, food-identification

I had a meal in one of the restaurants at the base of the Batu Caves in Malaysia that served a dish that I quite liked, but I failed to record what I ordered. I'm looking on Google Maps and I believe the restaurant is called "Dhivya’s Cafe".

The food was vegetables, at least potatoes if I recall correctly, served in a yellow curry-like sauce. There were pods in the curry that I think may have been mustard seed but could be wrong. It was served with bread.

Any ideas? Thanks.

Edit: Based on a comment I looked at the picture again and suspect it must have been the restaurant over. I've edited my question.

[image]

Also, here is a picture of the bread they served with it: https://pinoyfamilytravels.files.wordpress.com/2012/10/pinoyfamilytravels20120916-0001dhivyascafe.jpg

Comment: Hello Robert and welcome to the site! Admittedly, wer are quite a widespread bunch, but IMHO that is a bit too vague. You'd need someone that knows the restaurant and recognizes the dish -based on a rather vague description... I also doubt that potatoes would be served as [Jain food](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jain_vegetarianism).

Comment: This crepe-like dish looks like an Indian dosa (sometimes spelled dosai), and the probably coconut chutney in the center sort of matches that theory. Could be a touch of sambar on the upper right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have on your plate is the most eaten pancake in the world - Dosa. This is a South Indian dish and since there are many South Indians living in Malayasia, I don't think finding this there is an extreme coincidence. There are many varieties of Dosa and the one on your plate definitely looks like Rava Dosa(a variety of Dosa cooked with more semolina in the regular Dosa batter).

For more insight into Dosa, you can have a look at this Wiki page:

http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dosa

Dosa is served usually with Sambhar(the liquid yellow thing on your plate) which is like a lentil stew made with some vegetables and seasoned with mustard seeds and other Indian spices, coconut chutney(the white sauce) and takkali chutney(the orange sauce). Takkali in tamil means tomato so this chutney has tomato as its base seasoned with roasted lentils, onion and spices.